# Oracle SQL View takes only columns but not the data

Tags: oracle

I created this view

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.*, p3.*, p4.*, p5.*
FROM proizvodi_1_nivo p1,proizvodi_2_nivo p2,proizvodi_3_nivo p3,proizvodi_4_nivo p4,proizvodi_5_nivo p5
WHERE p2.sif_proizvod_1=p1.sifra_proizvoda_1
AND p3.sif_proiz_2=p2.proizvod_nivo_2
AND p4.sif_pro_3=p3.proiz_nivo_3
AND p5.p_sifra_4=nivo_4_proizvod
```

and when it's created I can see all the columns' names, but it doesn't retrieve any data. I created many other views in this way but I only have problem with this one. Could it be related to constraints?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you know your result will be the Cartesian product right. You need to optimize your query to work efficiently and you need to change this.

**p5.p_sifra_4=p4.nivo_4_proizvod** from last column. you forgot p4.

Comment: Thank you, I added the missing p4, but it still does not work, i need to create a view on these 5 tables that are connected, i don't know any other way

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting. Are you getting any error messages

Comment: Everything looks good. Could you revalidate all field names and confirm there is problem. Also please put in some screenshots if problem exist.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. I am using sql developer wizard to create this view. When I finish I get message no sql errors and when I click ok columns are created, but when I click on data tab there is nothing. Could it be datatypes maybe?

Comment: When you click on data are you getting any error in log? Does select query yield the same no result?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, but I found that I had two missing rows and that was the problem, now it works. Thank youu